# Can I use a Wok ring on a gas range?

Tags: equipment, cookware, wok, stove, gas

I have just purchased a GE Cafe gas range. The user guide indicates:

> Do not use a wok on the cooking surface if the wok has a round metal ring that is placed over the burner grate to support the wok. This ring acts as a heat trap, which may damage the burner grate and burner head.
>   Also, it may cause the burner to work improperly. This may cause a carbon monoxide level above that allowed by current standards, resulting in a health hazard.

However, I have read several times on the web that using a round bottom wok with a wok ring yields optimal results when cooking on a gas range.

What do you think?

Source: [Use and Care Manual](http://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=49-85147.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find it amusing that your range warns you the cooking ring will **work as intended**.  It's **supposed** to be heat trap, and focus heat on the bottom of the wok.

That said, they are also correct that it may discolor the burner grate.  I can't really say what your grates are made from, and many cooking materials discolor at high temperatures.  I think the main idea behind this paragraph in your manual is to save them from warranty replacements for discolored grates.

I also find it highly suspect that a wok could damage the burner itself.  They are usually ceramic, in direct contact with open flame, and **any** pan traps heat to some degree.  Burners get **HOT** and have to be able to take it.  Although the little decorative cap on the burner might discolor as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should follow the manufacturer's instructions for whichever piece of equipment is more expensive. They have spent significant time and effort researching and testing how their equipment works.

In addition, knowingly using equipment in a way specifically warned against by the manufacturer will in almost all cases void your warranty.

Comment: True on the warranty comment, but there's a certain expectation of being able to use something for the purpose for which it was purchased.  Ultimately, if you are concerned call GE and ask if you can use the stove to cook things.  If they say no, return it.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [Heartland Legend](http://www.heartlandapp.com/en/ArchivedProducts/Ranges/Legend.htm) range.  So far, the best technique I've found is to remove the grate altogether and balance a round-bottom wok directly on the burner.

I've tried wok rings but they have problems:

1. Not enough oxygen gets to the flame, and
2. Heat is trapped at the bottom and doesn't flow up the sides.

I'm thinking that a wire wok ring is the way to go.  The only one I've been able to find is Joyce Chen's J31-0063 Chrome Steel Wire Wok Ring.  I ordered one from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004RBTL)  and am waiting to see if it works better.

Does anyone else have experience with wok rings on high-perfomance gas ranges?

Comment: This is a great article on [how to modify your stove for a wok](http://thaifoodandtravel.com/blog/adapting-the-wok-to-your-stove/), including the use of wok rings.

Comment: Here's the [evaluation](http://www.amazon.com/review/RDMZA8HME0QKD/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00004RBTL&nodeID=&tag=&linkCode=) that I posted on Amazon for the [Joyce Chen J31-0063 Chrome Steel Wire Wok Ring](http://www.amazon.com/Joyce-Chen-J31-0063-Chrome-Steel/dp/B00004RBTL/)

Answer (score 3):

Melting of "wok" burners is common when flat bases pans are used. They reflect the heat back. Always follow the manufacturers directions!Useing a wok with a ring on the bottom will most likely damage the cooktop. A good wok on a good burner doesnt need such rings.

Answer (score 3):

All wok rings are not created equal; quality ones are made of cast iron.

Try to find one made specifically for your gas range: They are designed to lock onto the grate and function as an extension of the grate. A ring that is designed for your range  makes cooking in a wok an absolute joy as the wok is steady and balanced and heats evenly without fear of wobbling, sliding or over heating your range..

I recommend going to the web site of your range manufacturer and ordering it, if it's an option. 
If your particular make of range doesn't have the accessory, try to find a cast iron one from another gas appliance company that's as close to your grate configuration as possible , but keep in mind, nothing will fit as good, and be as safe and steady as the one cut specifically for your own model. The wok ring plays an important safety role in cooking in a wok.

Our wok has become a permanent part of our gas range as we use it for everything. The convenience of having a big sauce pan/ bowl/ fry pan always on top and ready for fire makes a nice addition to our kitchen..

Answer (score 1):

I have used my wok and wok ring on my indoor gas range several times with no problem.  The metal grates that usually cover the eyes are removable, and I always remove the grate on the eye that I use before placing the wok ring around the burner.

Keep in mind, it is preferable to use an outdoor propane burner as you will get the higher heat that is optimal for wok cooking and stir-frying.  I use the wok ring on my outdoor burner as well.

Answer (score 1):

Good wok rings have round sections cut out to stop excessive build up of heat and fumes.