# Heat maximiser ring

Tags: stove, kitchen-safety

Would a ring around a gas burner that would enclose the space between the burner and the pan be safe? (Maybe it needs oxygen to burn, carbon monoxide, I don't know.) The purpose of this would be to prevent heat from escaping out the sides. Similar to a [wok stand ring](https://goo.gl/images/p2YkZo)

Comment: Please see this answer: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8137/can-i-use-a-wok-ring-on-a-gas-range?rq=1  If that doesn't cover your question, please detail exactly which additional information you are seeking.

Comment: I've seen these called pot skirts before (possibly in a camping context)